# How to check if IntelliJ IDEA is properly installed?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have downloaded IntelliJ IDEA from Linux Download site and followed the steps.But with idea.sh script execution, I got different folder layout comparing with the instructions from the coursera course web-site.
This is mine idea window
[image]
This is the one from coursera
[image]

I do not have any folders in src. How to check if the installation was successful?

Comment: If you don't have any folders in src, then create them. The folder structure of a project doesn't have anything to do with the Idea installation itself.

Comment: Yours is a "pure" (no build management like maven, gradle or sbt) java project and the one from coursera is a sbt based project.

Comment: @meistermeier Yes,I understand now!